# vba code only works on a few sheets instead of all expected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

To start I'm just a beginner on vba codes and I try to find a lot on internet.

I made a code where users of the workbook click on a command button to insert a row on all the sheets in the workbook except for 4 of them. It worked fine but after make some adjustments to the workbook I suddenly noticed it now only works for 6 of the 16 sheets. I only adjusted the code by adding an exclusion sheet.

The button is on the first sheet so the code is also behind that sheet.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'insert row button
    On Error GoTo ext:
    'set variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim position As Integer
    position = InputBox("Before which row do you want to insert? Enter a position higher than 10", "position")
    If position < 10 Then
        MsgBox ("The position is lower than 10")
        GoTo ext:
    Else
    'insert row on all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "WORKSHEET - DO NOT DELETE" And ws.Name <> "WORKSHEET- stab template" And ws.Name <> "Version History - Do not delete" And ws.Name <> "WORKSHEET- stress studies" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ws.Range("A" & position).EntireRow.Insert
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next ws
    End If
Exit Sub
ext:
End Sub
```

Since I'm just a beginner I don't know where to start.
I did try to see if the position of the worksheets had an influence on the working of the code. what I mean by that is that the first sheet where the code didn't worked anymore, I moved that to the back to see if the code would go further then 6 sheets but this wasn't the case.

Comment: Remove the statement `On Error GoTo ext:` and retry: Likely you get a runtime error that is hidden by the error handler.

Comment: Add `Else: Debug.Print ws.Name` after `Application.EnableEvents = True` and check result in immediate window. Are any of the sheets protected ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes all sheets are protected I also added your suggestion but nothing appears in the immadiate window, The code gets executed on the first 5 sheets and then it stops

Comment: @ FunThomas I have tried your suggestion and indeed I get an error message: Insert method of Range class failed when I click debug he goes to the 
line: ws.Range("A" & position).EntireRow.Insert